# Custom $routeParam Separator in angular.js

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs

I want to have urls like `http://example.com/#/news/{abc}_{def}_{ghi}` where `{abc}, {def}, {ghi}` are all parameters. Note that the parameters are separated by underscores. How can I achieve this? I tried with `/news/:param1_:param2_:param3` and `/news/:param1\_:param2\_:param3` but none of them worked. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply calling it :params, then just doing params.split('_') either in route resolve or your controller?

Comment: I am sorry but I am really a n00b with angular. Some code example will be helpful.

Comment: Done! Used this: `var params = $routeParams.photoIdentifier.split('_');` Thanks for the tip!